# Image button generator for language names

Tags: image, button, localization, internationalization

I am looking to create jpg/png buttons with text as various language names. But the online tools don't seem to recognize the non-english words like language names for arabic, thai and hindi etc.

I tried http://dabuttonfactory.com/ with text as name of the language in local characters and all I see is ??????.

[image]

Any pointer or online resource to create non-css image buttons would be of great help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the fonts. The online tool you mentioned has limited fonts and none of them support the scripts you want to create buttons for. I just searched around and found [this service](http://www.grsites.com/generate/generator/2001/) which apparently has a wider variety of fonts and also lets you to upload your own font. The caveat is that it seems to be a paid service.